# Can we apply the extreme value theorem in this true-false question?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, extreme-value-theorem

**Problem**.  Is it true that $h(x) = f(g(x))$ has global maximum or global minimum if $g$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous in $[c,d]$ with the image of $f$ contained in $[a,b]$?

**Attempt**.  I say no because it's not clear that $h(x)$ is well-defined.  Nothing is said about the image of $g$.  For $f$ to be well-defined, the domain of $f$ must be the same as the image of $g$.  Without a guarantee that $f$ is well-defined, $h$ has no guarantee either, so we cannot use the extreme value theorem here.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the problem? Maybe the problem should say that the image of $g$ is contained in $[c, d]$?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking.  (Thanks for fixing the typo!)  Thank you.  I'm gonna change the problem and solve it that way.  With this fix, $h$ does become well-defined, a composition of continuous functions is continuous and then we apply the extreme value theorem.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the argument that I had in mind.